# How can I put null in the resolver's return value using type-graphql?

Tags: typescript, graphql, typeorm, typegraphql

I'm a newbie. ( The sentence might be weird because I use a translator. Sorry!  )

I have a question because there is a part that cannot be solved while using `type-graphql`.
Using the `Object Type` of `type-graphql`, I made the `graphql` type(?) and set the `nullable` of the `Field` to true.
And I made a resolver, and I set that model to the resolver's return value type.

However, if the return value of the Resolver has `null`, the error below will occur.

`Type 'null' is not assignable to type 'string | undefined'.`

How can I do?...
Putting an empty string seems to be a less elegant way.

[image: Object Type]
[image: Resolver]

Comment: I found the answer.
Don't try to assign null, just omit it.